# Derivation of word человецех

Tags: этимология

The phrase 'в человецех благоволение' means goodwill among men. What is the nominative of человецех?  It appears to be old Russian.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language.SE! Don't add a signature - your user card is added automatically below your post.

Answer (score 5):

This is not "old Russian" but Church Slavonic language, obviously.

Though the Nominative case is just the same as in pre-reform orthography: "**человѣ́къ**".

Answer (score 2):

It is Church Slavonic.

> Nominative single case was "человѣкъ"
>
> Nominative plural case was "человѣцы" or "человѣци" (both spellings were used).

There was an orthographic reform of Russian Language in 1918 in which the letter "ѣ" was replaced by "е", and letter "ъ" at the end of the noun was removed. This reform didn't apply to Church Slavonic. Nevertheless when scripture is quoted outside of church texts modern orthography is used.  Hence producing "человецы" and "челевецех"

Comment: Thank you very much Vitali.  From what you have written, I take it that the Prepositional/Locative case Plural would be, in modern orthography be человецех?  Tom

Comment: That is the correct conclusion.  I, personally, consider it Prepositional case, rather than Locative case.  There is the original example that you used "на земли мир, а в **человецех** благоволение."  Another example is "Сказание о **человецех** незнаемых в восточной стране и языцех розных."  Note that the word "языцех" (languages)  changes in the same in prepositional case way as the word "человецех"